# Political correctness version of TGIF Thank God It's Friday

Tags: word-choice

Sometimes I see "TGIF" Thank God It's Friday. But "God" is politically word. I need a word "Thank __ It's Friday."

Comment: I don't think "God" is a "political" word, and even if it was, there is no reason to change it there as TGIF is a fixed phrase and a trademark. But... With the whole "they" debate, maybe: Thank Divinities It's Friday? ;)

Comment: "Thank Goodness It's Friday"? Or just rephrase, "I'm glad it's Friday".

Comment: Just say TFIF instead.

Comment: But you're happy with Frigg?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Friggin' happy!

Comment: *TGIF* is not normally taken literally, and few people perceive it as having religious implications, just like few people think that *OMG* (as used in SMS messages) has any religious implications.

Comment: I always thought God was a religious word, explicitly divorced from politics in the Christian tradition: "Render therefore unto Cæsar the things which are Cæsar’s; and unto God the things that are God’s".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An understandable question, as some people might see flippant use of the phrase as blasphemous. "Goodness" is a commonly accepted euphemism in such cases (often used in phrases like "oh my goodness").

Comment: I asked my aunt about this very thing once. She was a Colonel in the Salvation Army, and probably the most convinced Christian I have ever met. She said "Why shouldn't we thank God for something that makes us feel good, and for getting us through the week?" She felt that God should be part of people's everyday lives, and not just the solemn, formal, Sunday parts, so she didn't mind people saying "Oh! God!" when they were surprised or shocked. Some of her colleagues disagreed, but that never stopped her. I have to say I myself am an atheist.